# unable to get array values from one while splitting csv to new line awk

Tags: shell, awk

```
echo "Main1,one,two,three,four" |awk '{ split($1,a,",");for (i in a) print i,")",a[i]; }'
```

Actual output:
2) one
3) two
4) three
5) four
1) Main1

Expected output:
1) Main1
2) one
3) two
4) three
5) four

I tried below command and missed the last value:

```
echo "Main1,one,two,three,four" |awk '{ split($1,a,",");for (i in a) print i-1,"\b)",a[i-1]; }'
```

Output:
1) Main1
2) one
3) two
4) three
0)

Unable to find why the first value is printed at the last.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest:

```
echo "Main1,one,two,three,four" |awk -F ',' '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) print i")",$i }'
```

Output:

```
1) Main1
2) one
3) two
4) three
5) four
```

Answer (score 3):

*By default, the order in which a ‘for (indx in array)’ loop scans an array is not defined; it is generally based upon the internal implementation of arrays inside awk.* Source: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Array-Traversal.html

If you want to process the array in index ascending order, use:

```
n=split($1,a,",")
# maybe an if(n) here
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    print i,")",a[i]
```